# Catch and change url request for delete

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm making a card component with react and I want the possibility to delete this card.

I created a `menu list` with a href and a `data-toggle modal` like this:

```
<MenuItem href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#confirmDelete' data-destroy-url={`http://foo.com/${this.props.card.id}`}> delete </MenuItem>
```

It opens a window where I have to confirm to delete this card template but when I confirm it doesn't work because there is no route for:

`[Delete] http://foo.com/`

But I want to delete `http://foo.com/cardId`

Is there anyway to change this request url with the good one ?

For my card component I use RMWC.

Thank you all.

**Update:**

Maybe I should add this information, in the past, the card component was made with html on Ruby on Rails like this

```
<%= link_to t(".delete"), '#', data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#confirmDelete", destroy_url: card_template_url(card_template)} %>
```

I already did a menu based on the same example which work perfectly

It was like this before:

```
<%= link_to t(".duplicate"), '#', data: {toggle: "modal", target:
"#duplicateModal", source_duplicate: card_template.id.to_s} %>
```

and I did this on react:

```
<MenuItem href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#duplicateModal' data-source-duplicate={this.props.card.id}> duplicate </MenuItem>
```

This exemple work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it have the correct url? The one in your snippet passes the card ID already

Comment: I don't know, I did another menu for editing the card, it look same with delete but it work correctly. I'm start to wondering if my `data-destroy-url` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Like Dominic is saying, the card ID is being passed correctly. Not sure why you want to hard code the URL though, I would change the URL to: data-destroy-url={`/${this.props.card.id}`} if it's on the same domain.

Comment: But I keep to have `404 not found` is there a part where I could give more details ?

Comment: You can edit your post

Comment: I updated my post with new informations